# Show the following is a linear transformation:

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be defined by $$T(x, y, z) = (2x + y, x − z, x + y^2).$$

Determine whether or not T is a linear transformation. If it is, justify. If not, show why.

I'm mainly just checking my work.

I concluded that $T$ is not a linear transformation. This is because when showing the vector additions are equal, the last term will not work out. This is because of the $y^2$ term.

Is this true?

Comment: Yes! That is true

Comment: A simple counterexample is $T(0, 1, 0) = (1, 0, 1)$, but $T(2 \times (0, 1, 0)) = T(0, 2, 0) = (2, 0, 4) \not= (2, 0, 2) = 2T(0, 1, 0)$.

Comment: As a sanity check, each component of the output should contain only sums of inputs times coefficients (which could be 0). So having constants (i.e. 2x+3y + 7), quadratic, cubic, trig functions, absolute values, logs etc will instantly make it not a linear transformation. The $y^2$ is a dead giveaway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the above is not a linear transformation, because of the $y^2$ sitting in the third term. The best way to bring this out is to exhibit a counterexample explicitly showing the issue. $T(0,1,0) = (1,0,1)$ and $T(0,-1,0) = (-1,0,1)$, so $T(0,1,0) + T(0,-1,0) = (0,0,2)$.

However, $T((0,1,0) + (0,-1,0)) = T((0,0,0)) = (0,0,0) \neq (0,0,2)$. Hence, $T$ is not linear.